# How to call GA script when user in dashboard of website only after login?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-analytics

I'm trying to check how many user go to page dashboard only after success login to the website.

What I'm doing now is put the Script of GA in the dashboard view ,but how to make it only run when the dashbord open after login ?

Comment: Any code to show? .... You could use a session var (a boolean), thats changed to true on 1st visit to the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just use a "if" statement to distinguish whether login or not, and put your Script of GA inside the block.